# Cordova with Windows Azure Storage, if the access to my container is public, do I still need authentification?

Tags: cordova, azure, azure-blob-storage

So I'm using Cordova with Windows Azure Storage and I'm using the plugins file-transfer and file from Cordova to download a file with public access from Azure. I get the error code 1 (FileTransferError.FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR). I am pretty sure my URL is correct, so I was wondering if it was due to me not adding authentification to the headers... But since it's a public file, do I really need the authentification?

Here is my code for Cordova, if that may help:

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI("https://MY_ACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net/MY_CONTAINER/test2.txt");
var fileURL = cordova.file.dataDirectory;

fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    fileURL,
    function(entry) {
        alert('entry');
        alert("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
    },
    function(error) {
        alert("error code" + error.code);
    },
    false
);
```

Comment: If the container is public, then you don't have to specify authentication. Best way to test if the container/blob is indeed public, just try to access the blob through a web browser by typing the blob URL in the browser's address window. HTH.

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes, I just tried it, and the file indeed is accessible! The reason why it wasn't working was my fileURL path wasn't complete (I had to add the filename to the end of the path).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who might get in the same problem as me, it was the fileURL path that was incomplete. At the end of the fileURL, you have add your file's name, so mine would be:

var fileURL = cordova.file.dataDirectory+"test2.txt";